# Question getting blurred ! Are many of you seeing this?

Tags: discussion

Today while browsing through questions i observed something rather peculiar: [image]

The screenshot explains it.As you can see themiddle question has sort of become blurred .I notice that this happens to a heavily downvoted *answer*  but this is something I am seeing for the first time in a question!(not to mention this has one upvote which I guess is trivial in this case).

Are many users seeing this problem or is it just me?and what could be the reason?

Comment: Did you choose to ignore either tag in the middle question?  Check your profile page, click on the tab "Edit Profile and Settings", and from there, on the left hand panel, you'll see "Tag watching and ignoring". Click on it.  You'll see a list of any tags you're watching, and any that you are ignoring.

Comment: I ignore the tag *numerical-methods*, so whenever such questions appear on the main page, they are "greyed out" just as your screen shot shows.

Comment: @amWhy that explains it i by mistake ignored the combinatorics tag (by my random clicking) i will delte this question if you think it is obvious

Comment: No need to delete the question.  It happens often enough that the fade out confuses users.

Comment: @amWhy OK thanks for your time (that reminds me that i have to be more cautious while moving my cursor)